# How can I do to when the erorr show the pic?

Tags: omnet++

When I build project
This erorr show[ undefined reference to `virtual thunk to veins::TraCIScenarioManagerLaunchd::finish()]

Comment: this version i used omnet++ 5.6.2  veins 5.1 sumo 1.8.0 inet 4.2.2

Comment: also when i build veins the erorr is                                                                               undefined reference to `virtual thunk to veins::TraCIScenarioManagerLaunchd::finish()

Comment: Please post errors or code as text not images.  Also without the code it would be rather hard for us to diagnose the issue.  But it looks like you have declared an variable that you are then re-declaring.  Also please use the [edit] link below the question if you have additional details,

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.